# iOS Map URL parameters for searching nearby

Tags: ios6-maps, apple-maps

Our app used to display Google Map in UIWebView and show keyword search results near User's current location like so:

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=pizza&sll=36.02667514703798%2C-78.94532340586088&z=12
```

Which works well and returns all pizza restaurants near the given coordinates.

Now we are required to open the native Map app on iOS devices.  So according to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html)

We changed to

```
http://maps.apple.com/?q=pizza&sll=36.02667514703798%2C-78.94532340586088&z=12
```

which opens native Map app and search for pizza, but the results are displayed on the entire US map, not at all near the specified coordinates.  Like it ignores or doesn't recognize sll parameter.

What am I doing wrong? How do I show results near User's current location? My test device is iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix it but according to that same page you linked to:
'The latitude and longitude points (in decimal format, comma separated, and in that order) for the map center point.'
Your example is not comma separated. Maybe worth trying that?